# Changing Transitions in views created by Xcode 4.2 Storyboard

Tags: iphone, view, storyboard

When I create a story board in Xcode 4.2, it seems that it assigns a view transition. What do I do to get access to the code so I can change the transition (e.g. slide right, slide left, fade, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to go to storyboard, then click on the connection between your view controllers, then go to the connection tab on the right pane, you'll see identifier, style, transition. change the transition to any of the four. that should do it without programing. if you need to hard code it let me know and i'll drop the code snippet by. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your storyboard.
2. Make the whole thing visible with all the views.
3. Click on the connection arrow from your button to it's view.  That arrow connection will then show the following pane where you choose what kind of segue.  See photo.

[image]